# Window Batch file - Current folder name gets truncated

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch

On my Win7 x64 box, when I run this command to find the current folder name

`for %* in (.) do echo %~n*`

it works for folders with alpha characters. However, for folder names that contain numeric values only, the last part gets truncated.

E.g.

```
C:\temp\2.4.0> for %* in (.) do echo %~n* # outputs 2.4
C:\temp> for %* in (.) do echo %~n*       # outputs temp
```

Not sure why this quirky behavior is happening. Is there another way to find out just the current folder name? By "current" I mean the folder from which the bat file was run.

Comment: what is the ~n for? ~ truncates if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Wutnaut A [list of batch parameters](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true). `~n` expands to a file name

Comment: does ~n behave the same way for folders? or does he want ~p?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a folder name like "2.4.0", Windows will treat "2.4" as the name, and ".0" as the extension.

So if you want the full name, including extension, then you need to use `%~nx*`.

That is mighty odd looking code by the way. Using `*` as a FOR variable is likely going to throw the average person off.

Comment: Ah! That explains!  Thanks for pointing out the odd variable name. It wasn't intentional but now I know a way to confuse the next person (if I wanted to) ;)!